# Server side facebook windows console app

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to discover the possibilities with Facebook API, and want to create console application that can get all feeds of a given facebook page, where I have a user that is registered as administrator.
So the console application should be:
- Notify new post received
- Post replys to new feeds

So, after reading the Facebook API documentation, I can see that what I probably want to use, is a PAGE TOKEN, and I need a USER TOKEN before I can retrieve a page token.

I'm discovering the .net SDK, and wondering if this is usable for a server-side only app, like my console will be?? Or should I go for the more custom road, and create HTTP requests/responses based on the graph web api??

Can anyone please explain how you initialize a Page Token (including the user auth etc.), from a console application, which doesn't have any webbrowser control??? 
All docs and blogs I've found so far, has been targeted for ASP applications.

Comment: You can not get a user access token without user interaction; you need a web browser (of some sorts) to achieve that. But you need to get a user access token only once, to generate a page access token – if you then extend the page access token, it will have no default expiry. (But it might become invalid f.e. when the user that created it changes their FB password.) So you can perform all the necessary steps by just calling the respective URLs as described in the login flow documentation in your browser, if you don’t want to implement any of that in your code.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll need to generate a LoginUrl and show that on a webpage in order to get a user signon, and a user token in return, if I'm not wrong??